# echoing out parts of an Array?

Tags: php, facebook, arrays, echo

I have the following array that I get as an output from facebook:
http://www.paste.to/v/1jntlnml

With the following code-

```
$stream = $facebook->api_client->stream_get('',128342905144,'0','0',30,'','','','');

foreach($stream as $wallpost) 
{
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($wallpost);
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

So I get the data that I need, but I want to call the individual variables within this array. For example, echo out the [message] for each post.

Since it only loops once, I cant `echo $wallpost['message']` or anything similar.

any idea?

Comment: Not sure I understood why you can't do $wallpost['message']. Also, is the output in the pastebin the content of $stream or $wallpost?

Comment: when I echo $wallpost I get this:

Array

Array

And when I loop though the foreach, it only loops once

Comment: because you have to do echo $wallpost['message'];

Comment: Almost There. This code seems to work so far with a few errors:




foreach($stream as $wallpost) {
    
 
 $i = -1;
 while ($i <=10){
 $i++;
 echo '<p><strong>';
 echo $wallpost[$i]['message'];
 echo '</strong></p>';
 //do this code;
}

Answer (score 0):

If the output of `echo $wallpost` is Array Array, I assume $wallpost contains the arrays from the pastebin, e.g.

```
$stream = Array(
  // $stream[0]
  Array(
    // $stream[0][0]
    Array('message' => 'msg1'),
    // $stream[0][1]
    Array('message' => 'msg2'),
  ),
  // $stream[0]
  Array(
    /* other stuff */
  )
);
```

In which case you get the messages by iterating over the first array, containing the messages like this

```
foreach($stream[0] as $wallposts) {
    echo $wallposts['message'];
}
```

As an alternative, wrap the returned array into a [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) to traverse the entire array in one go:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveArrayIterator($stream),
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST));

foreach($iterator as $key => $val) {
    if($key === 'message') {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

*Note: in your case, using the Iterator is rather pointless though because you know the second array does not contain any elements with posts in it and the first array is not nested.*

Comment: Hrm, when I use $stream[0] or $stream[1] I get the following:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: @Wes that implies $stream has associative keys instead of numeric keys. Can you do a var_export($streams) and put that into the pasty please.